# Spring4 MVC serialize enum as string with quotes

Tags: java, spring, jackson

i have a rest controller in a spring boot mvc container

```
@RestController
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping("rest/login")
    public Response login() {
        return Response.GRANTED;
    }

    public static enum Response {

        GRANTED, DENIED;

    }
}
```

I have to use double quotes for checking the return type after request a rest resource. how to avoid the double quotes?

```
$http.post("rest/login", $scope.data).success(function(data) {
  if (data === "\"GRANTED\"") {
   alert("GRANTED")
  } else if (data === "DENIED") {
   alert("DENIED")
  };
```

@RestController
public class LoginController {

```
@RequestMapping("rest/login")
public String login() {
    return Response.GRANTED.name();
}

public static enum Response {

    GRANTED, DENIED;

}
```

}

bring the result I want but I want the type safe return type Response and not String.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you considered returning HTTP status codes instead?

Comment: I did. Its similar to code with null. On the one hand you interpretate null as no value. On the other hand it could be an unexpected runtime error. I want an architecture that always returns a successful status code. if something real unexpected occurs I will receive a real error status code and I can see it on the javascript console.

Comment: Many different statuses exist, for a good reason. An unexpected runtime error in the server will lead to a response with the error 500. Return an error 400 (bad request) or 401 (unauthorized) to clearly signal the actual functional error. It's not similar at all to relying on null to signal an error, and it's how HTTP is supposed to be used.

Comment: The controller is returning JSON, so you should parse it using `JSON.parse(data)`. This will return "GRANTED" or "DENIED", so `alert(JSON.parse(data))` has the same behaviour as your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `@RestController` is like a `@Controller` annotated with `@ResponseBody`. That is, each handler is implicitly annotated with `@ResponseBody`. With any reference type other than `String` (and a few others), the default target content-type is JSON.

The 6 data types in JSON are Object, Array, Number, String, true, false, and null. How would you map an `enum` constant? The default that Jackson (which backs the default JSON `HttpMessageConverter`) serializes an `enum` constant to a JSON String. That's arguably the best matching JSON data type.

You could force it to write the value without quotes by providing your own `JsonSerializer`

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ResponseSerializer.class)
public static enum Response {
...
class ResponseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Response> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Response value, JsonGenerator jgen,
            SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeRaw(value.name());
    }
}
```

but I don't recommend it since you wouldn't be producing valid JSON.

You should really consider what others have suggested and use the various HTTP status codes.

Comment: I will think about your post. Your code example goes in the right direction. Is there a mechanism that allow to configure the jackson serialization for ALL enums?

Comment: @asmsys Not really. Check out Jackson's `EnumSerializer` to see how they do it, but it's part of the infrastructure as far as I know. That means it will be hard to change. I don't know of a workaround that would apply to all enums.